# How do I make my changes to XML-related source files take effect?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

I want to make changes to the xmldom and XMLDoc files. I tried to, but I don't know how to test those changes because the program does not seem to be running the code in those files. I tried using a ShowMessage to see if that code was being accessed but it never showed up. Even if I rename the directory the files are in, the program still compiles fine as if it is not actively reading the files at run time but instead has the information stored elsewhere.

How can I change these namespaces and then make sure that the changes are being included in my next compile?

*Update*

Well i'm looking for an answer in general..  Because I have had this problem in multiple situations.. But for specifics [Changing XML node attribute value gives "Namespace error"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11794540/changing-xml-node-attribute-value-gives-namespace-error) (here the answer talks about changing the 'AdomCore_4_3') I want to be able to change it and have the change show up when I compile.

Comment: They will be compiled as *.dcu files sitting probably somewhere in your `Delphi\xx\lib` directory (don't have Delphi XE to be more precise).

Comment: so if I deleted the *.dcu files that would cause the new changes to be compiled?

Comment: Yes, it should, but I'd rather rename them instead of deleting. And there might be some cache keeping the files loaded (but I'm not sure about it). So if it won't take effect, try to restart IDE(s).

Comment: You need to describe your scenario in sufficient detail so that we could reproduce it. Did you write these pascal files?

Comment: Hmm Okay, so I renamed the .dcu but it didin't rebuild it when I restarted my IDE.. what would you try at this point?

Comment: What do you mean by namespaces? They came in with XE2. Tell us everything about these files. Where are they? Where are the ones you are changing? How are you compiling them? Are you using packages? Details!!

Comment: Okay how about we start with the case on the link I put in my update above.  I want to modify the AdomCore_4_3 unit, as bundled with Delphi 2010.

Comment: And what have you done so far? Please don't tell me that you modified the source code in the Delphi installation directory.

Comment: I found that if I copy those units I want to modify to the directory of my project then I can modify the code and the changes are loaded when I compile..  Thanks for your help everyone, and your concerns.. I did end up modifying one unit from the source code installation directory but I changed it back when I learned I can just copy the file to the directory of my project and then make changes from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you are not making changes in the `interface` section of the units, only the `implementation` section, then you can disable use of Runtime Packages in your Project Options and then add the modified source files directly to your project.  The compiler will compile them into new .DCU files and use them instead of the default .DCU files.

Answer (score 4):

If you've removed the compiled DCU files from your environment, and your changes still aren't being compiled into your project, then you either aren't really using those units at all, or you have run-time packages enabled.

With run-time packages, the compiled code is accessed from the BPL file, not the DCUs. You're not allowed to distribute modified BPL files, so if you're going to modify the Delphi-provided source code, you need to make sure you're not linking the package with the XML units to your project. You can control that in your project's linker options.

Comment: Thank you, do you know what the name of that package is?  Also I have been looking around in the options and I see a Delphi Compiler "Linking" But I don't see anywhere where packages are specified..  Could you explain how I get there?  Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I guess it's in the package section instead of the linker section. Find the "build with run-time packages" option, and then either clear the check box or edit the list of packages to omit the one that contains the unit you're modifying. Last time I used Delphi, the list was a simple edit box with a semicolon-separated list of package names.

Comment: Thanks for the input Rob, it's good to know that distributing modified BPL files is prohibited.